# Reverse Axes of pgfplots Ternary Plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ternary-diagram

I am trying to make a ternary plot, however the default axis is opposite of what I need to accomplish. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\pgfplotsset{width=9.5cm, height=9.5cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ternaryaxis}[
ternary limits relative=false,
xlabel= x, 
ylabel= y, 
zlabel= z,
xmin=0,
xmax=100,
ymin=0,
ymax=100,
zmin=0,
zmax=100,
clip=false,
disabledatascaling,
label style={sloped}
]

\end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The outcome that I want would look something like this (apart from the text being reversed):

[image]

I don't know if this is even possible and the manual was no help.

Comment: Question looks identical to [flip-x-and-y-axis-of-ternary-graph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192043/flip-x-and-y-axis-of-ternary-graph). However not marking duplicate since there is no solution for that question either. 'x dir=reverse, y dir=reverse, z dir=reverse` are not working on ternary plots. Currently, I believe there may not be a solution to this.

Comment: I can not really understand your question. Could you please add some more details?

Answer (score 4):

Put `xscale=-1` in `tikzpicture` options.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\pgfplotsset{width=9.5cm, height=9.5cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1]    %%% <------------------
\begin{ternaryaxis}[
ternary limits relative=false,
xlabel= x,
ylabel= y,
zlabel= z,
xmin=0,
xmax=100,
ymin=0,
ymax=100,
zmin=0,
zmax=100,
clip=false,
disabledatascaling,
label style={sloped}
]

\end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without labels flipping:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\pgfplotsset{width=9.5cm, height=9.5cm,}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[xscale=-1,]
\begin{ternaryaxis}[xscale=-1,
ternary limits relative=false,
xlabel= x,
ylabel= y,
zlabel= z,
xmin=0,
xmax=100,
ymin=0,
ymax=100,
zmin=0,
zmax=100,
clip=false,
disabledatascaling,
y label style={rotate=-60,anchor=south,yshift=3ex},
y tick label style={anchor=west},
x label style = {rotate=60,anchor=south,yshift=3ex},
x tick label style={anchor=east},
]

\end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I missed something, please let me know.