# Reversing axis of ternary diagram

Tags: pgfplots, axis, ternary-diagram

Is it possible to reverse an axis in a ternary diagram? The command `x dir=reverse` does not seem to work:

Here is a minimal working example: the result is the same with or without this option.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ternaryaxis}[%
  x dir = reverse % -> no effect ?
]%

\addplot3 coordinates {
(0.85,0.15,0.00)
(0.82,0.13,0.05)
(0.73,0.14,0.13)
(0.82,0.06,0.13)
(0.84,0.00,0.16)
};
\end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As my question is close to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192043/flip-x-and-y-axis-of-ternary-graph), I've just seen a feature request as been opened [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/54/). I deduce that there is currently no solution...

Comment: That is right, I currently don't see any solution. So you could file another feature request, because *flipping* axis is something else than *reversing* axis.

Comment: How about the second [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213359/121799) of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213278/121799), which has almost the same title?

Comment: @marmot : I would like to reverse only one axis (so as to have two "100" labels at the same corner and two "0" labels at another.

Comment: Hmmh, does that make sense? How can anything be 100% x and 100% y?

Comment: @marmot : You're right, after double-check, that does not really make sense to reverse only one axis, this should become counter intuitive. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that makes too much sense, but you can always put some phantasy labels.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ternaryaxis}[%
x tick label style={opacity=0},clip=false
]%

\addplot3 coordinates {
(0.85,0.15,0.00)
(0.82,0.13,0.05)
(0.73,0.14,0.13)
(0.82,0.06,0.13)
(0.84,0.00,0.16)
};
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,20,...,100}
{\node[anchor=south west] at (axis cs:{1-#1/100},0,{#1/100}) {#1};}
\end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]